How to Subscribe to Call Progress Events for Inbound Calls in Twilio
I'm currently working on a project where I need to track the progress of inbound calls in Twilio, specifically subscribing to call events like completed, failed, or any status changes for a specific CallSid.
Context:
I've set up an inbound call flow in Twilio for a specific number.
From this flow, I can retrieve metrics like from, to, CallSid, startTime, and status using a trigger object.
I then call a Twilio Serverless Function to capture these metrics as soon as the call starts, and I save the initial status (in-progress) in my database.
My requirement is to update the database with the final status of the call, such as when it is completed or failed.
Issue:
I understand that Twilio provides call progress events for outbound calls, as described in this post https://www.twilio.com/en-us/blog/introducing-call-progress-events-flexibly-track-and-control-your-outbound-calls-html, but my scenario involves inbound calls initiated by the customer to a Twilio number.
I’ve tried looking for ways to subscribe to call events based on the CallSid but haven’t been able to figure it out.
Question:
Is there a way to receive notifications via a webhook when the status of a specific inbound call changes? How can I implement this in my current setup?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!
